# HIVE : Why does Hive generate mapreduce job on select column from tablename Vs not generating mapreduce for select * from tablename?

Tags: hive

Why does Hive generate mapreduce job on select column from tablename Vs not generating mapreduce for select * from tablename?

Answer (score 3):

When a simple statement like this is executed `select * from tablename`, what hive does is simply to fetch the data from the file stored in hdfs and bring it out in a columnar output format. Basically it generates a statement like

```
hadoop fs -cat hdfs://schemaname/tablename.txt
hadoop fs -cat hdfs://schemaname/tablename.rc
hadoop fs -cat hdfs://schemaname/tablename.orc
```

Or in whichever format your table's file is stored.

If you try selecting a column or adding a where clause to the query or using any aggregate on the table, MR comes into picture for obvious reasons.

Comment: What if you have multiple nodes? Would select * run MR then?

Comment: That's the beauty of HDFS. It runs a map reduce job irrespective of the number of nodes. The logical system is separated from the physical one.

Comment: ok, so if your data is spread among nodes, but you are still only doing `SELECT *`, then it won't do a map reduce job, right?

Comment: yeah..for a `select *` only a `hadoop fs -cat hdfs://schemaname/tablename.txt` kind of statement will be issued.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you run a normal 'select *', a fetch task is created rather than a mapreduce task which just dumps the data as it is without doing anything on it. Whereas whenever you do a 'select column', a map job internally picks that particular column and gives the output.

There was also a bug filed for this to make 'select column' query run without mapreduce. Check the details here: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-887