# Hive select - Fetch and MapReduce

Tags: hadoop, hive, partitioning, bucket

I have two tables

> 1. External Table A
> 2. External Table B With paritioned and bucketed columns
>
> Table A has 5 columns (lets say c1,c2,c3,c4,c5)
>
> Table B has 5 columns (c1,c2,c3,c4 partitioned on c5 and buketed on c1.

I run the following queries

```
1. select * from A where c5="x" and c1="y"
2. select c1,c2,c3 from A where c5="x" and c1="y"
3. select * from B where c5="x" and c1="y"
4. select c1,c2,c3 from B where c5="x" and c1="y"
```

All of these do not use `MR` but just the fetch operator.

Q1: `MR` or Fetch - Does this depend on the size of the file or its the same behavior always?

Q2: 2nd and 4th queries' behaviors are contradictory to the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26008645/hive-why-does-hive-generate-mapreduce-job-on-select-column-from-tablename-vs-n). Is this a recent improvement?

```
5. select count(*) from A where c5="x" and c1="y"
6. select count(*) from B where c5="x" and c1="y"
```

Q3: Obviously these 2 needs `MR` but 5 is twice faster than 6. Ideally, 6 should be faster as the table B is partitioned and bucketed and the query is based on those columns. What could be the possible reasons? I ran the queries multiple times.

Note: I use HDP 2.3

Answer (score 0):

**Regarding Q1 and Q2 :**

There has been recent upgrades in hive starting from version 13 which uses the hive table stats, column stats extensively just like those when the table is stored as ORC i.e. the analyse feature. This avoids the execution of MR for count(*) queries and all. You could check the table properties of your table using the show create table syntax , where you could see the table count getting updated upon adding records etc. These values also get recorded in the hive metastore.

Refer [this](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/Column+Statistics+in+Hive) , [this](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/StatsDev) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31671249/hive-count-query-is-not-invoking-mapreduce)

**Q3:**

The MR execution benchmarks as you have mentioned might be true when we handle small datasets. The partitioned and bucketed tables might not perform better for small datasets as it has to go through the entire MR stages unlike the non-partitioned and un-bucketed tables.

Hope I have given you a small gist on your query.

Comment: Thanks Nidhin. On Q2, the table stats is not run for this table but still no MR. May be a different feature as part of the improvement?